# Hit points bar wont fill completely, calculation only happens once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a hit points bar which is supposed to fill up by 0.1 each time the ball object collides with the goodOrb object. However the bar fills up by 0.1 only on the first collision. It does not move when the ball collides again.

I tried Debug.Log the value of the variable hitPoints which stores the current amount the bar is filled by. This variable is initialized to 0, I have another variable called increase which is set to 0.1, each time the two objects collide variable increase is supposed to be added to hitpoints. But this is happening only once. Debug.Log(hitpoints) shows 0.1 only once.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class goodOrb : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int maxHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth;
    public Image barImage;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
     public float increase = 0.1f; //amount to increase bar each time a collision happens

    public float hitPoints = 0.0f; // current amount the bar is filled by

          //  public AudioSource collisionSound;
    int scoreValue= 5 ;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Start()
    {
            GameObject Filler = GameObject.Find("Filler");

            Image barImage = Filler.GetComponent<Image>();


    }

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {  

        ParticleSystem ps = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();    

        if(other.tag=="Ball")
        {        
             ps.Play(); 
             HitPoints();
             scoreManager.score += scoreValue; 
             // barImage.fillAmount = (float)currentHealth / (float)maxHealth;

           // collisionSound.Play();
        }



    }

    void Update()

    {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void HitPoints()
    {

               GameObject Filler = GameObject.Find("Filler");

            Image barImage = Filler.GetComponent<Image>();

            hitPoints = hitPoints + increase;
                barImage.fillAmount = hitPoints;
             //print(hitPoints);
             Debug.Log(hitPoints);


    }


}
```

I expect increase to be added to hitpoints each time the collision happens and the hitpoints bar to be filled.

Comment: Sounds like this script is only on the one item.. there maybe other reasons why its not doing it more, but from this its hard to tell

Comment: the script is on the GameObject goodOrb it doesn't need to be on the filler bar

Comment: when the ball collides with the goodOrb 0.1f is supposed to be added to the hitpoints variable

Answer (score 0):

1- make sure the ball collides with same orb object every time.
2- make sure one collider isTrigger is true.
3- make sure trigger function is called every time ball collides. 
by doing this
     `void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        Debug.Log (other.tag);
}`

Comment: the orb object is spawned randomly there many of them and yes the function is called every time

Comment: Increase bar fill amount by doing this...
` barImage.fillAmount = barImage.fillAmount+0.1f;`